# Simple integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

There is a simple integral equation:
$$\int_0^\infty p(s) ds = 1- \frac{1}{\lambda}p(0).$$
Do you know how to solve it for $p(0)$ given we know $p(s)$ for $s>0$? Or maybe some references to methods how to solve it?

Comment: Perhps I'm missing something but this seems to be a rather weird question: if we know $\;p(s)\;$ then we can, in theory at least, understand  that equality...otherwise we can't possibly know why it is true.

Comment: what are you solving for? $\lambda$ ?

Comment: for $p(0)$. Changed the question. Thanks!

Comment: @cherep in terms of $\lambda$?

Comment: @DonAntonio after the correction, the question makes sense now(if it possible to find a value of $p(0)$ that is, i am not really sure)

Comment: Well, it still is a weird question imo since then it all is a matter of high school algebra...??

Comment: @Sabyasachi in terms of $\lambda$ and all $p(s)$ for $s>0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean a fixed value, not the integral. Funny answer though.

Comment: Or perhaps it is meant to be a differential equation...? Hard to tell

Comment: If you don't know the function, @Sabyasachi, how can you possibly know the integral??

Comment: @DonAntonio I have no idea. Just wondering. I guess $p$ has some restrictions, which are not mentioned here.

Comment: Exactly @Sabyasachi: *not mentioned here* . Well, in fact it seems to be worse: it is said **we know the function** .

Comment: @cherep you might want to answer that^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty p(s) ds = 1- \frac{1}{\lambda}p(0)\implies p(0)=\lambda\left(1-\int\limits_0^\infty p(s)ds\right)\ldots\ldots?$$

Comment: *Technically* this is right. +1

Comment: $p(0)$ is still under the integral... How to deal with it?

Comment: @cherep, what do you mean the constant $\;p(0)\;$ is "under the integral"??

Comment: @cherep maybe you mean $p(s)$ is still under the integral? (I wonder why *s*? Weird choice of variable without context)

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean that $p(0)$ is unknown and need to be found... The integral is from $0$ to $\infty$, thus, if we do not know $p(0)$, we cannot take the integral, can we?

Comment: @cherep yes we can. Define the integral as, $$\lim_ {x\to0^+}\int_x^\infty p(s)\,ds$$.

Comment: We **do** know $p(s)\forall s\gt0$

Comment: yes, it makes sense. Thank you!